# Unix get lines between timestamps on multiple files

Tags: unix, logging, awk, grep, timestamp

I keep daily log files (*like logfile-2022-01-01.log, logfile-2022-01-02.log, and so on*).
Every line on the files starts with a timestamp, e.g: *[2022-05-01 10:00:34.550] ...some strings....* --> this being YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.sss

I need to filter all the lines between two timestamps, this could mean search in more than one file.
For instance:

> logfile-2022-01-01.log
> [2022-01-01 00:00:25.550] here comes some logging info
> [2022-01-01 00:02:25.550] here comes some more logging info
> ....
> [2022-01-01 23:58:29.480] here comes some more logging info

> logfile-2022-01-02.log
> [2022-01-02 00:01:25.550] here comes some logging info from the next day
> [2022-01-02 00:04:25.550] here comes some more logging info from the next day
> ....
> [2022-01-02 23:59:29.480] here comes some more logging info from the next day

I wish to extract the lines between 2022-01-01 20:00:00 (this is contained in the first file) and 2022-01-02 08:00:00 (this is contained in the second file).
I'm expecting to get something like this:

> [2022-01-01 23:58:29.480] here comes some more logging info
> [2022-01-02 00:01:25.550] here comes some logging info from the next day
> [2022-01-02 00:04:25.550] here comes some more logging info from the next day

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

So far I've tried using this:

> grep logfile-2022-01-01.log logfile-2022-01-02.log | grep "here comes some" | awk
> '/^2022-01-01 20:00/,/^2022-01-02 08:00/ {print}'
>
> grep logfile-2022-01-01.log logfile-2022-01-02.log | grep "here comes some" | awk
> '$1" "$2 > "2022-01-01 20:00" && $1" "$2 < "2022-01-02 08:00"'
>
> grep logfile-2022-01-01.log logfile-2022-01-02.log | grep "here comes some" | awk -v beg='2022-01-01 20:00' -v end='2022-01-02 08:00' '{cur=$1" "$2} beg<=cur && cur<=end'

Both run without errors but didn't print anything

Comment: please update the question with the code (`awk`? `grep`? something else?) you've attempted and the (wrong) results generated by your code

Comment: added my attempts

Comment: your first command in each pipeline is `grep`?  did you mean `cat`?  why `grep` for the string `text` ... are  you only looking for lines that include the string `text`? (`text` isn't mentioned in your description)

Comment: please also confirm a) the files may contain duplicate rows and b) you want to remove duplicates from the final output

Comment: Thanks for pointing the error on the example!
I was adapting my attempts to keep it as generic as possible. 
Yes, I'm filtering by some text. 
I don't mind having duplicates.
If I remove everything after the "awk" command, everything works fine, it's just no filtering by the timestamps, it's giving me every single row on the log files that matches the grep filter
I only need to fix the timestamp filtering
I'm a novice to unix commands

Comment: fwiw, sample inputs show timestamps from May (05) while youre code attempts are looking for entries from Jan (01)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding some lines to both input files so we can confirm matching on specific strings; also updating file names to match the timestamp date (`05` instead of `01`):

```
$ head  logfile*
==> logfile-2022-05-01.log <==
[2022-05-01 00:00:25.550] here comes some logging info
[2022-05-01 00:02:25.550] here comes some more logging info
[2022-05-01 23:56:30.332] here comes more logging info
[2022-05-01 23:58:29.480] here comes some more logging info


==> logfile-2022-05-02.log <==
[2022-05-01 23:58:29.480] here comes some more logging info
[2022-05-02 00:01:25.550] here comes some logging info from the next day
[2022-05-02 00:02:39.224] here comes logging info from the next day
[2022-05-02 00:04:25.550] here comes some more logging info from the next day
```

Tweaking one of OP's current set of code:

```
$ cat logfile-2022-05-01.log logfile-2022-05-02.log | grep "here comes some" | awk -F'[][]' '$2 >= "2022-05-01 20:00" && $2 <= "2022-05-02 08:00"'
```

Where:

- replace first `grep` with `cat`
- add `awk` dual field delimiter of `]` and `[`
- modify`awk` to only compare the 2nd field
- modify `awk` tests to use inclusive ranges
- update file names and datetime stamps for May (`05`) instead of Jan (`01`)

This generates:

```
[2022-05-01 23:58:29.480] here comes some more logging info
[2022-05-01 23:58:29.480] here comes some more logging info
[2022-05-02 00:01:25.550] here comes some logging info from the next day
[2022-05-02 00:04:25.550] here comes some more logging info from the next day
```

While this generates OP's desired results (per comment OP has stated duplicate lines are ok), once you decide to use `awk` there's typically no need for separate `cat` and `grep` calls.

One unified `awk` idea that utilizes input variables while also removing duplicate (consecutive) lines:

```
start='2022-05-01 20:00:00'
end='2022-05-02 08:00:00'
string='here comes some'

awk -F'[][]' -v start="$start" -v end="$end" -v str="$string" '

$2 >= start         { printme=1 }
$2 > end ".000"     { printme=0 }                # assumes "end" does not include milliseconds

printme && $0 ~ str { if ($0==last) next         # skip duplicate consecutive lines
                      print last=$0
                    }

' logfile-2022-05-??.log
```

This generates:

```
[2022-05-01 23:58:29.480] here comes some more logging info
[2022-05-02 00:01:25.550] here comes some logging info from the next day
[2022-05-02 00:04:25.550] here comes some more logging info from the next day
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this worked like a charm.
I guess I need to review the awk -F command more in depth to get familiar with it and the patterns to use.